Blender Pole Target Rotates Wildly When IK Target, PoleTarget, or Any Other Bone Gets Moved
I have IK constraints all over this thing, but the knees are broken. They were fine when I first made them, and now they're doing this:
Crazy Knees Being Obnoxious via Imgur
I've tried replacing the bone with a copy, remaking the IK constraint, and replacing the ankle and knee controller to no avail. I have no idea why it does this. Please, help!

Hello please share your file (the armature only)

@moonboots Sorry it took me so long to get back to you! Here's the armature.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XyovV4nIFUS7GUu9imF9dQ-KfuS9st2w/view?usp=drive_link

The head bone is also misbehaving. I deleted the pole target on one leg and it's not going crazy, but I want/need the pole target control. Also, you should hit alt+H, I have some parts hidden

You need to parent the pole target bones to the root or to the IK controller, not to the shin bones, otherwise there's a hierarchy conflict (also called circular dependency).

Thank you so, so much!!!
